# Android How to share facebook text using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-sdk-3.0, android-facebook

I have a button which on pressed shows the possible ways of sharing text

```
llShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            }
        });
```

since Facebook does not allow predefined text, I will have to use their SDK to make it possible somehow... Can I do it like this, and what else do I need to add to make their library working? I still havent made any custom classes for share (are any needed?)

Comment: you can implement custom dialog and use "me/feed" to directly post on user`s wall

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it impossible to conclude you need to spent some more time on reading documentary about the Android Facebook SDK.

I am sharing with you link to article that describe how to implement share in android platform.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Comment: I have read that article, but still does not help me to solve my issue

Comment: Ok lets start from very beginning please tell me. You import Facebook SDK to you're project?

Comment: Ok do you authenticate user with you're application?

Comment: I want it to just use the Facebook app if its available, just like the usual share intent uses your already installed apps (twiiter, google+, tumblr)...